# Where does `at` redirect its output?

Tags: cron

I tried to use `at`

```
me@host:~$ echo ls | at now +1 minutes
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 3 at Fri Mar 15 20:58:00 2019
```

I wait more than 5 minutes but did not see any outputs.

Where does 'at` redirect its output? Can I direct it to the terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `man at`:

> ```
>                    The  user will be mailed standard error and standard
> output from his commands, if any.  Mail will be sent using the  command
> /usr/sbin/sendmail.
> ```

The same as for `cron`, if you don't have a configured mail transfer agent (MTA) running on your system, the output will simply get discarded - if you look in the `syslog` you will likely see an error something like

```
atd[28729]: Exec failed for mail command: No such file or directory
```